# PHP Mailer function mail() error

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I'm working at a online form, but i can't do it run

Somebody can help me with this?

This is my problem:

the following from address failed: villarrealbli01@gmail.com : called mail() without being connected

I don´t know if my code isn´t working or what, i´m using PHP Mailer, and this is my PHP code

```
<?php
$mail_gmail='villarrealbli01@gmail.com';
$pass_gmail='***********';

require 'php_mailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require 'php_mailer/class.smtp.php';



$mail_destino='lethal_blizzard_rap@gmail.com';

$datos = $_POST;

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->SMTPSecure = "tsl";

$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

//$mail->Host = "localhost";

$mail->Port = 567;

$mail->Username = $mail_gmail;

$mail->Password = $pass_gmail;

$mail->From = $mail_gmail;

$mail->FromName = "Contacto";

$mail->Subject = "Contacto desde el sitio web";

$mensaje = "Se ha recibido una nueva solicitud de contacto, los datos son los siguientes:  <br/>";

$table = "<table border='1'>";
    $table.= "<tr>";
        $table.= "<td>Nombre</td>";
        $table.= "<td>".$datos['nombre']."</td>";
    $table.= "</tr>";

    $table.= "<tr>";
        $table.= "<td>E-mail</td>";
        $table.= "<td>".$datos['email']."</td>";
    $table.= "</tr>";

    $table.= "<tr>";
        $table.= "<td>Comentarios</td>";
        $table.= "<td>".$datos['comentario']."</td>";
    $table.= "</tr>";

$table.= "</table>";

    $mail->Body = $mensaje."<p></p>".$table;

    $mail->SMTPDebug = false;

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->AddAddress($mail_destino);

    $resultado = "";


    if($mail->Send())
    {
      $resultado = array('estatus'=>true,'mensaje'=>'DATOS ENVIADOS EXITOSAMENTE');
    }
    else
    {
      $resultado = array('estatus'=>false,'mensaje'=>'ERROR '.$mail->ErrorInfo);
    }

  echo json_encode($resultado);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this config? :

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Or

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got your port & protocol mismatched. port 465 is for ssl and port 587 is for tls.

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // port 587

$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // port 465
```

Also use this code  `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1` to enable debug

Comment: Its not TSL, it is TLS.

Comment: edited, thanks Sven :D

Comment: It doesnt work with this maybe its another thing?